# Get data from Firestore and properly append to array

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to fetch data from Firestore. I've already got the following code but how do I properly append to `shelters`?

Current error:

> Value of type '[String : Any]' has no member 'title'

```
class FirebaseSession: ObservableObject {

    @Published var shelters: [Shelter] = []

    let ref = Firestore.firestore().collection("shelters")

    getShelters() {
        ref.getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
            if let err = err {
                print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
            } else {
                for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                    let value = document.data()
                    let shelter = Shelter(id: Int(value.id), title: value.title, image: value.image, availableSpaces: value.available, distance: value.distance, gender: value.gender)
                    self.$shelters.append(shelter)
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

```
class Shelter {

    var id: Int
    var title: String
    var image: String
    var availableSpaces: Int
    var distance: Double
    var gender: String?

    init?(id: Int, title: String, image: String, availableSpaces: Int, distance: Double, gender: String?) {

        if id < 0 || title.isEmpty || image.isEmpty || availableSpaces < 0 || distance < 0 {
            return nil
        }

        self.id = id
        self.title = title
        self.image = image
        self.availableSpaces = availableSpaces
        self.distance = distance
        self.gender = gender
    }

}
```

EDIT:

```
let shelter = Shelter(id: value["id"] as? Int ?? -1, title: value["title"] as? String ?? "", image: value["image"] as? String ?? "", available: value["available"] as? Int ?? -1, distance: value["distance"] as? Double ?? -1, gender: value["gender"] as? String ?? "")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let shelter = Shelter(id: Int(value.id), title: value.title, image: value.image, availableSpaces: value.available, distance: value.distance, gender: value.gender)
```

Here `value` is of type `[String:Any]`. So you cant do `value.title` . You need to do `value["title"] as? String ?? ""` and Similarly for id,image,distance,etc.

So the final code becomes:

```
let shelter = Shelter(id: Int(value["id"], title: value["title"], image: value["image"], availableSpaces: value["available"], distance: value["distance"], gender: value["gender"])
```

Downcast it accordingly.

**UPDATE**

replace your code with this

```
if let shelter = Shelter(id: value["id"] as? Int ?? -1, title: value["title"] as? String ?? "", image: value["image"] as? String ?? "", available: value["available"] as? Int ?? -1, distance: value["distance"] as? Double ?? -1, gender: value["gender"] as? String ?? "") { 
   self.shelters.append(shelter)
} else { 
   print("provided data is wrong.")
}
```

Comment: I somehow now get the following error for append: `Cannot convert value of type 'Shelter?' to expected argument type '[Shelter]'`.

Comment: You can find my new `let shelter = ..` code within the edit.

Comment: @Tim i have updated the code. Also, which line is producing the above error? coz this should not happen.

Comment: Using your updated code did job, I just needed to unwrap `Shelter?` to `Shelter` using `shelter!` - I hope that's fine?

Comment: @Tim i have updated the answer to safely unwrap the shelter object using if let statement. Better use this as it wont crash your app if Shelter initialization failed.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of issues with the original code:

1. Instead of implementing a function to fetch the shelters, the following snippet in your code creates a computed property - not sure this is what you intended:

```swift
getShelters() {
...
}
```

I'd recommend replacing this with a proper function.

2. No need to use a `class` for your data model - especially as you seem to be using SwiftUI.
3. Instead of mapping the fetched documents manually (and having to deal with `nil` values, type conversion etc. yourself, I'd recommend using Firestore's Codable support.

I've written about this extensively in my article [SwiftUI: Mapping Firestore Documents using Swift Codable - Application Architecture for SwiftUI & Firebase | Peter Friese](https://peterfriese.dev/swiftui-firebase-codable/).

Here's how your code might look like when applying my recommendations:

```swift
struct Shelter: Codable, Identifiable {
  @DocumentID var id: String?
  var title: String
  var image: String
  var availableSpaces: Int
  var distance: Double
  var gender: String?
}


class FirebaseSession: ObservableObject {
  @Published var shelters = [Shelter]()

  private var db = Firestore.firestore()
  private var listenerRegistration: ListenerRegistration?
  
  deinit {
    unsubscribe()
  }
  
  func unsubscribe() {
    if listenerRegistration != nil {
      listenerRegistration?.remove()
      listenerRegistration = nil
    }
  }
  
  func subscribe() {
    if listenerRegistration == nil {
      listenerRegistration = db.collection("shelters").addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
        guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
          print("No documents")
          return
        }
        
        self.shelters = documents.compactMap { queryDocumentSnapshot in
          try? queryDocumentSnapshot.data(as: Shelter.self)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that:

1. we're able to do away with the constructor for `Shelter`
2. the `shelter` property will now be automatically updated whenever a shelter is added to the `shelter` collection in Firestore
3. the code won't break if a document doesn't match the expected data structure

I marked the `Shelter` struct as identifiable, so that you can directly use it inside a `List` view. `@DocumentID` instructs Firestore to map the document ID to the respective attribute on the struct.